# jQuery custom dropbox: how to tabindex

Tags: jquery, dropbox, tabindex

I'm using jQuery to customize my own dropbox but was wondering how I could apply the tabindex to it.

I try to use the hidden select focus/blur event but doesn't seem to work.

I also try to apply a tabindex attribute to my customize dropbox (a div) but without success.

Can someone have a sample or a link to show me how I can achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand what you're going for, but perhaps this will get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/2rCFV/1/

```
$(window).keydown(function(e){
    if(e.which === 9){ //tab
        var selected = $('.selected');
        selected.removeClass('selected');

        var tabIndex = +selected.attr('tabIndex') + 1; //plus sign at beginnign converts it to a number

        var next = selected.siblings('[tabIndex=' + tabIndex + ']');

        if(next.length > 0){ //if this element exists
            next.addClass('selected');
        }else{
            selected.siblings('[tabIndex=' + 1 + ']').addClass('selected'); //select the first one
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I image that you could have a variable - current selected item. You just catch user keyboard events and change the current selected item by adding/removing classes to corresponding div. When enter is pressed, call needed event based on the current selected item.

some kind of pseudo code:

```
var current = 0;

if(key = down){
    current++;
    currentElem.removeClass('active');
    currentElemen = currentElem.next();
    currentElem.addClass('active');
}

if(key = up){
    current--;
    currentElem.removeClass('active');
    currentElemen = currentElem.previous();
    currentElem.addClass('active');
}

if(key = enter){
    doStuff(current);
}
```

Hope this gives you an idea!